# Using find and wc -L to find files containing lines longer then 500 characters

Tags: linux, shell, find

I have this command:

```
find . -name "*.php"  -exec wc -L '{}' \;
```

And I believe it gives me the count of the longest line for each file. But I'm looking for a way to only print out the count and file location if the length is greater the 500.

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a crude script which does what you want

```
find . -name "*.php"  -exec wc -L '{}' \; |
  while read maxlinelength filename
  do
    if [ 500 -lt $maxlinelength ]
    then
      echo $maxlinelength $filename
    fi
  done
```

the output of the `find`-`wc` combination is piped to a `while read` loop which puts each line of maxlinelength and filename in the variables `$maxlinelength` and `$filename`. the `if` then checks whether `500` is less than `$maxlinelength` and if it is prints the values.